# Debugging a function called when hovering with the mouse over an org link

Tags: org-mode, org-link, edebug, org-ref

I am trying to debug a function called when hovering with the mouse over an org link. For example, I instrumented `bibtex-completion-apa-get-value` with `edebug-defun`. However, when I hover over an `org-ref`'s citation link, the help echo appears (showing the entry produced using `bibtex-completion-apa-get-value`) without going into an `edebug` session. So, how can I debug what's going on when I hover over an org link?

Comment: I would examine the text properties underneath -- `(text-properties-at (point))` and/or set the point and then `C-u C-x =` -- and see what makes the link tick, and then move forwards with debugging from there.  I don't use `edebug`, so I have no suggestion on using that utility.

Answer (score 0):

I just found a solution to something like this. It appears to me the help-echo function call is somehow shrouded so edebug does not get to it. The trick is to call the help-echo function while point is on the link in a regular (i.e. interactive) way so it does trigger edebug things.

The help-echo function on cite links is defined by a lambda function. It isn't a big deal in the end, we can get the lambda function from a text property at point, and then call it with the help-echo arguments. So, define this interactive function:

```
(defun orc ()
  (interactive)
  (funcall
   (get-text-property (point) 'help-echo) nil nil (point)))
```

instrument the function you want to look at. Then put point on the link, and run M-x orc. That should trigger an edebug on your instrumented function so you can trace through it.

This worked for me. Hopefully it will help you too.